# Setting up a Linux server with a public Static IP

Tags: ubuntu, routing, ip, nat, iptables

I have setup a Ubuntu Linux server in an office.  It should have a public IP so that outside users can access the internet.  Currently, it is set with a public IP, but is it supposed to have a local IP so that users in the LAN can access via private IP (e.g., `192.168.0.xx`) for faster speeds or file sharing?

For public IP somehow the router or something must know to route requests between the public IP and the local IP?

Comment: Do you require that the server have a public IP, or just be accessible via a public IP? There is a major difference in how you would set up either circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is acting as the firewall (NAT, Squid Proxy, etc.), then having an internal subnet is important too.  When doing this, however, it's also best to place the public (external) and private (internal) networks on separate physical NICs.

Setting up different IP address netblocks should not make anything noticeably faster or slower, but it will require that some care go into planning how you're going to organize your network.  For starters, on the server you'll only need to set the gateway to match the one that your ISP provided for your public Static IP address (NAT, proxy, etc., will use this on behalf of requests from internal computers).

The beauty of using private IP addresses is that you can have many computers, devices, etc., connected to the internet with a single IP address.  In fact, this is a very common setup with NAT, and one that occurs with broadband/wireless routers (e.g., what LinkSys sells en masse).

Some helpful links:

RFC1918 - Address Allocation for Private Internets (see section 3 on page 4)
  http://rfc1918.openrfc.org/

Step-by-step configuration instructions for NAT with IPTables
  http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables

A discussion in a forum about setting up what you want to do
  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=713874

How to Install and Configure DHCP Server in Ubuntu Server
  http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-and-configure-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu-server.html

Comment: The reason for my recommending that public and private networks be placed on separate NICs is to simplify security by isolating the private network from the internet (which should always be regarded as a danger zone since it is "public" after all).  You'll still need to configure iptables (or "pf" or whatever you choose to use) to be secure -- I recommend starting with blocking everything first then making exceptions ONLY for those services you intentionally choose to make available to the public (e.g., a web site, OpenVPN, ICMP for ping and traceroute operations, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It will always have the private IP. In a simple case, its lets say 192.168.1.10 and your router with public IP 123.456.789.10 forwards port 80 to 192.168.1.10. With that alone, you can access by both IPs, as well as a domain name if you have that set up to the public ip.

I host a server at home and this is how I have it, and it works just fine.